# ideas on designing folder monitoring and alert notification utility program

Tags: .net, windows-services, notifications, monitoring

I am just wondering, what would be the best way to design and implement a .NET utility program that can monitor directory and send out alert emails whenever there're changes in that directory, i.e. files created/modified/deleted.

Should I go with windows service or something? Or perhaps just run this program on schedule and detect the differences from the last run?  Can anyone give me some ideas and pointers?

Besides developing the program myself, there perhaps are some excellent free tools out there somewhere already.  Can anyone suggest any if you happen to know them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [file system watcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) to do this.  Be sure to read through the documentation to discover various quirks about it.

As far as the runtime design, you could implement a windows service but I'd get my functionality working as a console application first and switch to a service when I thought there was a reason.

You could separate the components out into an event queue, which also means going from 1 runtime component to three: 1. file monitor to produce events, 2. the database queueing events and 3. an emailer service to consume them.

There are really alot of options because you have all the components of a workflow system.  My suggestion is to keep it as simple as you can for what you need to produce at the moment, and increase the complexity as demand goes up.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. It's very useful. And I think I  agree with you. I probably just need to create a console program first for this one, just to keep things simple. Then see how I should go from there.